# How to limit the number of stomp clients in Spring, subscribing to a specific topic, based on a condition?

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket, stomp

I have been researching for a way to limit the number of clients who can subscribe to a specific stomp topic but have not yet understood, which could be the right approach according to my needs.

My use case is a game, which I am developing in Angular (ng2-stompjs stomp client) and Spring Boot Websockets (for the moment, the Spring in-memory message broker is in use).

The idea is that a user can be connected and subscribed to a "/lobby" stomp topic, and there he sees the opened game rooms, that could be in different statuses. for example, in-play or not started yet due to the low number of players joined.
I'd like to intercept and programmatically restrict a possible subscription of a client, to a specific "/room/{roomId}" topic, IF the MAX number of players has been reached, for example, 4. There could also be some simple client-side validation to restrict that, but I believe only client-side is not sufficient

So my main questions are:
How can a specific stomp topic subscription be intercepted in Spring?
Is it possible to return to the client-requestor some kind of error message that subscription could not be done?

I'd really appreciate your help, thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet, configuration, or what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement a StompEventListener which listens for subscriptions, in this we can have map mapping a destination(room number) versus the count of number of players in that particular room. if the count is already at max reject the subscription.

```
@Service
class StompEventListener() {
   private Map<String, int> roomIdVsPlayerCount = new HashMap<>();
   
   @EventListener
   public void handleSubscription(SessionSubscribe event) {
     StompHeaderAccessor accessor = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(event.getMessage());
     String destination = accessor.getDestination();

     String roomId = destination.substring(...); //Parsed RoomID
     if(roomIdVsPlayerCount.get(roomId) == MAX_ALLOWED_PLAYERS) {
       //Throw exception which will terminate that client connection 
         or, send an error message like so:
       simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend(<some_error_message>);
       return;
     }
     //So it is not at maximum do further logic to actually subscribe 
       user and
     roomIdVsPlayerCount.get(roomId) += 1; 
   }

   @EventListener
   public void handleUnsubscription(SessionUnsubscribe event) {
    ...
   }
}
```

Useful References:

1. [SessionSubscribeEvent](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/messaging/SessionSubscribeEvent.html) (For handling the subscriptions)
2. [ConvertAndSend](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/core/MessageSendingOperations.html#convertAndSend-D-java.lang.Object-). (For sending the error messages to client.)

**EDIT**

Please try sending the exception from a `channel Interceptor` since the above did not send the exception , so that it gets propagated to the client. The map we defined earlier can be defined as a bean in a separate class accessible(with @Autowired) to both event handler(for incrementing and decrementing) and TopicSubscriptionInterceptor(for validation).

```
@Component
class TopicSubscriptionInterceptor implements ChannelInterceptor {
    @Override
    public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel){
      StompHeaderAccessor accessor = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(message);
      String destination = accessor.getDestination();

      String roomId = destination.substring(...); //Parsed RoomID
      if(roomIdVsPlayerCount.get(roomId) == MAX_ALLOWED_PLAYERS) {
        //Throw exception which will terminate that client connection 
      }
     
     //Since it is not at limit continue 
    
    }
}
```

Useful reference for implementing a `TopicSubscriptionInterceptor`: [TopicSubscriptionInterceptor](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=luxons/seven-wonders/seven-wonders-master/backend/src/main/java/org/luxons/sevenwonders/config/TopicSubscriptionInterceptor.java)

Comment: Looks like a great suggestion. Although I cannot seem to stop the actual subscription. Tried throwing an exception and even sending back a message with simpMessagingTemplate, the actual subscription happens and the client continues receiving messages

Comment: @Luis Have added a a fix, please have a look after implementing the interceptor.

Comment: Having a custom ChannelInterceptor has to be the right approach. I will now be sending a custom message to the client, right before returning null - instead of throwing an exception. If we take a look at the ChannelInterceptor#preSend, it is invoked before the message is sent to the channel or message broker, but if null is returned, send will not occur - so the actual subscription in the broker won't happen. Throwing an exception would close the connection and send an ERROR frame, which was not very useful in my case. Nevertheless thanks for your help :)